# Deciphering a piece of music

Tags: music

For a puzzle I am trying to solve, I have to find a certain artist which should be derived from a piece of 'music'.

The only thing I am given is this image:
[image: The notes A5, D5, E4, C5, C4, G4, G5, 8th rest, D4, B4, D4, G5, G4, half rest]

The other puzzles were all code related, for example transforming pictures of croissants and dogs into binary, then converting the binary to ASCII. Another puzzle was taking licence plates, looking up which brand they belonged to and then taking all the first letters of these brands to form a new brand.

I therefore have the feeling that it is not simply playing the music to find the artist (I also already did try that). But probably some way of decoding music. I am not even sure if you actually have to be really good at reading notes, but since I am not so myself, maybe someone who is could have a better insight then me.

Thanks in advance if you are able to help me any further :)

EDIT:
The 120 bpm is not orignally from the puzzle, that is something which was added by me when I typed over the notes in a programm to hear what it would sound like.

EDIT:
The original picture (5646516514564.png):
[image]

Comment: When you converted the notes, did you make sure that the stem of the notes goes the same way as in the original? I'm also curious how you placed the rests vertically.

Comment: @MOehm The OP says they were just given the image, no?

Comment: @jafe: Yes, but the addendum says that the ♩ = 120 was added later, so are we really looking at the original image?

Comment: @MOehm Oh, right. I missed that.

Comment: @MOehm what do you mean by "rests vertically"? these are normal quarter and eighth rests

Comment: @Flying_whale: Yes, but rests don't have a pitch. You would normally just place them in the centre of the staves. (I can see how rests can be positioned vertically in sheet music where more than one voice is writen on the same staves, but not here.)

Comment: @MOehm ooooh, you are right, i didn't notice that

Comment: @MOehm The rests in the original are all on the same height I believe, I will try and see if I can attach a picture of the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artist is:

> [Michael Bublé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bubl%C3%A9)

The notes ...

> ... are not real music, of course. It's especially strange that the rests have a pitch; the rest symbols are usually placed in the centre of the staves.
>
>  If we encode the low C (the 5th note) as one, the low D as two and so on up to the high A, which is thirteen, we get:
>
>      13, 9, 3, 8, 1, 5, 12, (12), 2, 7, 2, 12, 5, (5)
>
>  The numbers in brackets are the rests, although it's not quite clear where to put them exactly, as they have no spatial anchor like the notes' heads. Converting that to ASCII yields:
>
>      MICHAEL (L)BGBLE(E)
>
>  The first part looks good. We probably need a means to "shift" the letters to the second part of the alphabet. The obvious mechanism is to use the length of the notes. All notes except the second one after the bar are eighth notes. The single quarter note is a U. (Except that it isn't: The second half of the alphabet starts with N, and that would mean the quarter note sits on T. Perhaps the querter note means to add 14, brcause 13 is considered unlucky.)
>
>  The rests are just space; they have the required length to fill the 4/4 bars.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bubl%C3%A9)? The quarter note would be the only letter that needs special treatment...

Comment: Yes, I just found it out. Seems that the original's unusually positioned rests threw me off track.

Comment: @MOehm sorry for the confusion of not posting the original, but thanks for the help! So how exactly are you enumerating the notes, what is the base number?

Comment: Yes, the rests in the original look more conventional. ´:)` The enumeration just means to give the notes numerical values, where the low C is 1. In other words, you don't call the notes C, D, E, ... but 1, 2, 3, ... and you don't wrap over after one octave.

Answer (score 1):

didn't look any further, but if this could help

> notes are *la re mi do do sol sol re si re sol sol* or *A  D  E  C  C  G   G   D  B  D  G   G*  depending on the standard.  
>  the eighth rest could be to mark the separation between artist's surname/name